# Reference for Introduction to Algebraic Geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am currently looking to study Algebraic Geometry. As I am totally new to the subject any reference for books to follow will be helpful, thanks in advance....

Comment: I found Brendan Hassett's book "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry" to be pretty easy to work with. It won't take you deep into schemes, or anything like that, but it gets through the basics pretty concretely, including elimination theory and projective geometry.

Comment: These ([one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/285355/120540) and [two](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/269446/120540)) posts by Javier Álvarez are quite ... voluminous. And searching [his answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a4058%20%5balgebraic-geometry%5d), they are not the only ones.

Comment: You shoud precise more about your background and your objective as algebraic geometry is a pretty big subject...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cox, Little, O'Shea: Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms.
This is the standard book at the undergraduate level.

Comment: Standard book? First time i hear about this book ;)